# Issue loading php_mysql.dll extension

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have been trying for a very long time to try and get mySql set up with php. The php install definitely works, and when I call phpInfo() I can see that my extension directory is being set.

When I uncomment the lines:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

I get an error when I try to restart my apache web service:

```
Windows could not start the Apache2.2 service on Local Computer.

Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.
```

I am not sure what to do, I have search for answers almost everywhere and have not found a solution. Any thoughts?

Here is what I have setup:

Apache 2.2,
PHP 5.2.17 (V6),
MySql 5.5

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext" (I have tried just "ext" and adding trailing "\" and no luck)

I have C:/php set up as an environment variable - as I stated earlier, php is working but I just can't get MySql setup.

Answer (score 1):

I double checked all of those, but those did not fix it.

FIXED IT:
I ended up deleting my install of php and reinstalling the thread safe V6 version and it fixed my problem.

Thanks for the advice guys.

Comment: For legacy purposes, I needed to install PHP on a Windows Server using IIS, and I was having the same issue. In my case, the opposite worked. I installed the NTS (Non-Thread Safe) version.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying your current libmysql.dll to C:\Windows\system32 (you should find it in the php root folder). This is quite often the reason for failing php/MySql installations on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Path environmental variable has C:\php\ext in it. If you add it in, reboot.

Try starting Apache from the command line to get the specific error message:
`httpd -k start`

...and check Apache's error.log file.

Do a system search for php_mysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll. If you have either one in your C:\Windows or C:\Windows\system32 directory, delete those files.